# Make chat feed awesome (or at least usable)

Tags: feature-request, chat

In the Stack Overflow JavaScript room, we wanted to add the feeds of the blogs of several prominent JavaScript developers. This is what we got:

[image]

This **sucks.** The format is totally unusable, there's no indication of which goes to what (the top link goes to the feed URL, the bottom link links to the actual post) none of the metadata (date, author, other media files that may be attached to the post) that the feed actually contains appears, which limits the usefulness of this feature to basically RSS feeds of sources that already trigger oneboxes on chat, like Twitter feeds.

What we need is probably something similar to what Stack Overflow blog posts have:

[image]

I would suggest something like this:

[image]

Comment: "not even the post title appears anywhere in the message!" What are you talking about? It's right there in your screen shot. I agree with the rest, though.

Comment: @balpha Uh yeah, the post title does appear in the message. I have an amazing capacity to miss the blindingly obvious sometimes >_>

Comment: Sooo, this seems like it's stalled? I was just thinking I'd really like to see the question author in the WordPress SE chat feed. Are we talking about the same thing in this Q? Missing the ability to add metadata in feed output seems to be the same issue OP had.